# does the patent examiner not have discretion over how many office actions or examiner's reports after October 3rd, 2022 in Canada?

Tags: law, office-action, examiner, canada, rules

[image]

So does the patent examiner not have discretion over how many office actions or examiner's reports after October 3rd, 2022 or is this table-misleading?

https://mcmillan.ca/insights/forecast-2022-expected-changes-to-the-canadian-patent-rules-part-2/